# Different spatial coverage in scenes downloaded from USGS LANDSAT data

Tags: python, rasterio, landsat, epsg, usgs

I am using M2M Python API to download scenes of Landsat 8 data for North America region, as shown in the code snippet below.

```
datasetName = "landsat_band_files_c2_l1"
spatialFilter =  {'filterType' : "mbr",
                  'lowerLeft' : {'latitude' : 31.8, 'longitude' : -157.99},
                  'upperRight' : { 'latitude' : 65.02, 'longitude' : -98}}
temporalFilter = {'start' : '2023-01-11', 'end' : '2023-01-13'}
serviceUrl = "https://m2m.cr.usgs.gov/api/api/json/stable/"
```

The band files I want are 5 and 7, the names are as given below

```
'LC08_L1TP_118066_20230113_20230113_02_RT_B5.TIF' 'LC08_L1TP_118066_20230113_20230113_02_RT_B7.TIF'
```

Now, to plot and visualise, re-projection to EPSG:4326 is required. But on reprojection, the lat-lon extent are totally different from what I had requested for

```
test = rxr.open_rasterio(all_landsat_bands[0], masked=True) #first band image path
test = test.rio.reproject("EPSG:4326")
test.rio.bounds()
```

The output:

```
(111.75961616451919,
 -9.73691271889413,
 113.84988985109456,
 -7.6224410148753226)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't on reprojecting the file, check the filename:

*LC08_L1TP_118066_20230113_20230113_02_RT_B5.TIF*

It's Landsat 8, level 1, path 118, row 66, date: 2023-01-13, and band 5.

The path/row 118/66 it's for Asia:

[image]

The boundary box is fine, the image is actually in those coordinates. The issue comes from M2M parameters used for downloading the files. [Check M2M Python API documentation](https://github.com/Fergui/m2m-api):

> boundingBox   Tuple (length 4)    Spatial bounding box expressed as
> (min_lon,max_lon,min_lat,max_lat) in EPSG:4326 projection. Example:
> (-126.471753, -112.426439, 32.135664, 42.399335).

So, for your case,you should use the following tuple:
`(-157.99, -98, 31.8, 65.02)`.

Try again using [Search by boundinx box](https://github.com/Fergui/m2m-api#search-by-a-bounding-box) approach